# Error(6,87): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "JOIN" when expecting one of the following/compound trigger

Tags: sql, plsql, triggers, oracle-apex

When I try to compile below compound trigger I got the error message. Please suggest what can be done to clear those error.

I tried to use normal trigger but its throwing ORA-04091 ERROR.

```
create or replace TRIGGER "WS5108"."AL_PROJECT_ORACLE_CODE_TRG" FOR
    INSERT 
  ON ITIB_REQUESTS 
  COMPOUND TRIGGER
DECLARE  
  V_CODE varchar (200);
  BEGIN
    IF :NEW."J_PROJECT_ORACLE_CODE" IS NULL THEN 
      SELECT distinct (PROJECT_ORACLE_CODE) INTO V_CODE
        FROM ITIB_PROJECT_ORACLE_CODE POC 
        JOIN ITIB_VPDOMAIN VP ON (POC.VP_DOMAIN = VP.VP_DOMAIN) 
       WHERE POC.VP_DOMAIN = (SELECT VP_DOMAIN
                                FROM ITIB_VPDOMAIN
                               WHERE ID = :NEW."VP_DOMAIN")
         AND CAPEX_CATEGORY = :NEW."C_CAPEX_CATEGORY" 
         AND :NEW."C_TOTAL_EURO" <= 250 ;
  END IF;

:NEW.J_PROJECT_ORACLE_CODE := V_CODE;

EXCEPTION

  when no_data_found then

  V_CODE := null ;

    END AL_PROJECT_ORACLE_CODE_TRG;
```

I am trying to add value for one column in table after new line inserted in that table if that column is empty. This column value I am taking from that select condition and new values which are inserted in table.

Comment: Did you wrote `delimiter /` before the  trigger definition?

Comment: The error points to line 6 character 87, which is the start of the `JOIN` keyword and so matches the error text; but the (long) select statement on that line looks basically OK. Which version of Oracle are you using, and which tool and version are you using to compile this? (I believe Forms still doesn't understand ANSI syntax, for instance...)

Comment: @OscarPérez no I didn't

Comment: @AlexPoole  I am using sql developer and Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error in your question title is the second of two; running the reformatted code in your question I see:

```
LINE/COL  ERROR
--------- -------------------------------------------------------------
2/1       PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DECLARE" when expecting one of the following:     function pragma procedure subtype type <an identifier>    <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> current cursor delete    exists prior before after instead 
8/9       PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "JOIN" when expecting one of the following:     , ; for group having intersect minus order start union where    connect
```

(with different line number due to reformatting). In general you should fix the first error reported first, as subsequent errors are often unhelpful and caused by side-effects of the earlier ones. That is the case here. If you fix the compound trigger syntax to address the error reported against `DECLARE` then the `JOIN` is no longer a problem either:

```
create or replace TRIGGER "WS5108"."AL_PROJECT_ORACLE_CODE_TRG"
  FOR INSERT 
  ON ITIB_REQUESTS 
  COMPOUND TRIGGER

  BEFORE EACH ROW IS
    V_CODE varchar (200);
  BEGIN
    IF :NEW."J_PROJECT_ORACLE_CODE" IS NULL THEN 
      SELECT distinct PROJECT_ORACLE_CODE INTO V_CODE
...
    END IF;

    :NEW.J_PROJECT_ORACLE_CODE := V_CODE;
  EXCEPTION
    when no_data_found then
      V_CODE := null ;
  END BEFORE EACH ROW;
END AL_PROJECT_ORACLE_CODE_TRG;
/
```

Basically, the main trigger body code you had needed to be in a `BEFORE EACH ROW` block, since it is a compound trigger.

Incidentally, you probably want `V_CODE` to be declared as `varchar2` rather than `varchar`, or as `ITIB_PROJECT_ORACLE_CODE.PROJECT_ORACLE_CODE%TYPE`. If you need that variable at all; the assignment back to the `:NEW` field probably wants to be inside the `IF` block (as if that is *not* initially null, you set it to `v_code`, which *is* then null!), but you can also select straight into the `:NEW` variable. So I think you really want something more like:

```
create or replace TRIGGER WS5108.AL_PROJECT_ORACLE_CODE_TRG
  FOR INSERT 
  ON ITIB_REQUESTS 
  COMPOUND TRIGGER

  BEFORE EACH ROW IS
  BEGIN
    IF :NEW.J_PROJECT_ORACLE_CODE IS NULL THEN 
      SELECT PROJECT_ORACLE_CODE
        INTO :NEW.J_PROJECT_ORACLE_CODE
        FROM ITIB_PROJECT_ORACLE_CODE POC 
        JOIN ITIB_VPDOMAIN VP ON (POC.VP_DOMAIN = VP.VP_DOMAIN) 
       WHERE POC.VP_DOMAIN = (SELECT VP_DOMAIN
                                FROM ITIB_VPDOMAIN
                               WHERE ID = :NEW."VP_DOMAIN")
         AND CAPEX_CATEGORY = :NEW.C_CAPEX_CATEGORY
         AND :NEW.C_TOTAL_EURO <= 250 ;
    END IF;

  EXCEPTION
    when no_data_found then
      null ; -- do nothing; :NEW.J_PROJECT_ORACLE_CODE is already null
  END BEFORE EACH ROW;
END AL_PROJECT_ORACLE_CODE_TRG;
/
```

I don't really see why this needs to be a compound trigger though, you aren't accessing the table the trigger is against (as you were in your previous question) and you only have a single scenario - only `before insert`; so a simple trigger would work here:

```
create or replace WS5108.TRIGGER AL_PROJECT_ORACLE_CODE_TRG
  BEFORE INSERT 
  ON ITIB_REQUESTS
  FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
  IF :NEW.J_PROJECT_ORACLE_CODE IS NULL THEN 
    SELECT PROJECT_ORACLE_CODE
      INTO :NEW.J_PROJECT_ORACLE_CODE
      FROM ITIB_PROJECT_ORACLE_CODE POC 
      JOIN ITIB_VPDOMAIN VP ON (POC.VP_DOMAIN = VP.VP_DOMAIN) 
     WHERE POC.VP_DOMAIN = (SELECT VP_DOMAIN
                              FROM ITIB_VPDOMAIN
                             WHERE ID = :NEW.VP_DOMAIN)
       AND CAPEX_CATEGORY = :NEW.C_CAPEX_CATEGORY
       AND :NEW.C_TOTAL_EURO <= 250 ;
  END IF;
EXCEPTION
  when no_data_found then
    null ; -- do nothing; :NEW.J_PROJECT_ORACLE_CODE is already null
END AL_PROJECT_ORACLE_CODE_TRG;
/
```

And even the query within that looks confused; you don't need the subquery:

```
...
      SELECT PROJECT_ORACLE_CODE
        INTO :NEW.J_PROJECT_ORACLE_CODE
        FROM ITIB_PROJECT_ORACLE_CODE POC 
        JOIN ITIB_VPDOMAIN VP ON (POC.VP_DOMAIN = VP.VP_DOMAIN) 
       WHERE VP.ID = :NEW.VP_DOMAIN
         AND CAPEX_CATEGORY = :NEW.C_CAPEX_CATEGORY
         AND :NEW.C_TOTAL_EURO <= 250 ;
...
```